# Csv write Double quotes

Tags: python, csv

I was creating a CSV from python's CSV writer, where I want the same data as the input CSV but some texts with double-quotes.
I have successfully added the text I wanted but I'm struggling with double quotes in the text.
The output file is giving me 3 double quotes instead of just 1.
Here is my code until now:

```
with open('test.txt',newline='') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
    data = [line for line in r]

with open('abc.csv','w',newline='') as f:
    w = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    w.writerow(["some of my text"])
    w.writerow(["some more: 123456"])
    w.writerow(["even more: 5555"])
    w.writerow([f"with a variable: {time}"])
    w.writerows(data)
```

the output of the inserted text of this code is like this:

"""some of my text"""

"""some more: 123456"""

"""even more: 5555"""

"""with a variable: 28th oct"""

Please suggest where am I missing to remove these triple quotes.

Comment: Do not add them to row

Answer (score 0):

> 3 double quotes instead of just 1

That is correct. In CSV, the `"` is used to surround values containing special characters. In order to include a literal `"` it must be escaped by doubling it.

So you get one `"` for the start/end of the value, and then two `""` to encode the quote in the value.

[RFC 4180 §2 ¶7](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#section-2)